# How to group by timestamp in data or data ingestion time?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I could see that spark streaming windowing function does the grouping only based on "when it received the data". I would like to do the grouping based on the timestamp field available in the data itself. Is it possible?

For example - The data creation timestamp is available as part of the data as 1 PM. But spark streaming received the data at 1.05 PM. So it should do the grouping based on the timestamp (1 PM) available in the data.

Comment: see Spark Structured Streaming's Watermarking

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to do the grouping based on the timestamp field available in the data itself. Is it possible?

No. Spark Streaming does not offer such a feature.

You should instead use [Structured Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) that does offer `window` function to group by.

Quoting [Window Operations on Event Time](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time):

> Aggregations over a sliding event-time window are straightforward with Structured Streaming and are very similar to grouped aggregations. In a grouped aggregation, aggregate values (e.g. counts) are maintained for each unique value in the user-specified grouping column. In case of window-based aggregations, aggregate values are maintained for each window the event-time of a row falls into.

Comment: Is it not possible with Spark 2.1 too?

Comment: `window` function's available as of Spark 2.0.0 (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$).